# Thunderbird does not (always) ignore folders

Tags: 12.04, sync, thunderbird

I have configured a number of folders in Hotmail where certain e-mails (like newsletters) are forwarded to. I installed Thunderbird on my home laptop and those folders are never synced, just the way I like it.

On my work laptop however, I have the same configuration but more folders are synced and I get a notification every damn time when I get a new e-mail. This annoys me a lot (because I have +30 unread mails so the overview of new mails is lost) and I don't seem to be able to find out how to ignore certain folders. Plus, it's weird that it works on the one system and not on the other.

The `When getting new messages for this account, always check this folder` is unselected in the folder properties. The Thunderbird version is Thunderbird 24.3.0 and I use Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

I believe under the folder's `Properties` you also have to go to the `Synchronization` tab and uncheck `Select this folder for offline use`.

Comment: It was already unchecked so that's not the answer. I think that it's the same setting as mentioned in my question but that it changed somewhere in the releases between 24.3.0 and 31.7.0

Comment: Well I have both the option you mentioned (found under the folder properties' `General Information` tab) and the one I mentioned, and having both deselected works for me under 31.7.0.

Comment: You're right, I also have both options. They were both unselected so no dice unfortunately. The weird thing is that the settings are the same between my work and home laptop but it doesn't act the same